# Refresh part of page with PHP/AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Yes, I know that you can refresh the page every number of seconds with AJAX but I want to be able to do this with PHP. Basically running a PHP script where I can say a command which then triggers AJAX to refresh the page.

I could not find this anywhere, no guide or post on here. Please lead me into the right direction. Thank you.

I am not asking you to write code, I am asking for you to tell me a method to do this.

Comment: If you want server to trigger something on the front-end, then you should try WebSockets.

Comment: traditional http has the client initiate requests and the server respond. If the server must initiate an action, you will need something else, like websockets

Comment: Got any good websockets I can use with PHP?

Comment: AJAX is only called from client side. You need a notication model.

Comment: Have a look at EventSource. I was playing with it the other day for something similar.Client makes http connection via javascript which remains open listening for server side pushes of data. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource

Answer (score 1):

You can't reload page that sending AJAX request.

If you sending request by JavaScript you can reload page only by JavaScript.

If you send `Location` header from PHP you get redirect for your `XmlHttpRequest` object. So use JavaScript for this.

For example you can do AJAX request to your server and write something like this in callback:

```
function(response) {
    var el = document.getElementById('el');
    el.innerHTML = response;
}
```

Comment: And you can do everything you want by AJAX, get part of page or full page and then manipulate with DOM